# How many files can select with input type file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to select 1000 images by use the following code.

```
<input type="file" multiple accept="images/*" />
```

and when i select 1000 images nothing happened.
But when i select 600,800 then withe the field it shows the number of selected files.

So my question is what is the limit to select files? and can i change that limit so i cna select 1000 files?

here is online [demo](http://phpfileuploader.com/demo/select-multiple-files-upload.php)
and also JSFiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BluAngel/zAN5s/)

Comment: @putvande: That question is for the backend (PHP server). OP wants to know how about client limits.

Comment: I check your suggested question they discuss about `max_file_uploads` it is set in my server 20 (but this 20 means 20 files in one request) so 1 thing is that am not doing anything at server right now and i just want to select in client side only. and also if i i want to send on server i will not doing that in one request. :) Thanks @putvande

Comment: See this [What is the max number of files to select in an HTML5 multiple file input?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16331118/3639582)

Comment: Please make duplicate with correct one :) The current suggested duplicate in not a duplicate of my question