# Trouble selecting more than 518 files for upload using ASP.NET FileUpload control

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, webforms

So my question is pretty straight-forward. I need to upload about 600 files and more (of PDF and CSV type), but the ASP.NET FileUpload control only allows me to select 518 files. Once I select more than 518, it says 'No file chosen'. Does anybody know why this could happen? Is there maybe a limit on the number of files that can be selected at a time? The number of files that I'll be uploading every month will increase, so I could reach 1000 files soon.

Your help is greatly appreciated.
Morné.

Comment: So just to make it clear, the problem occurs on the client only, before submitting the request to the server?

Comment: Correct. I only select the files from the file selection dialog, nothing more.

Comment: Haven't used webforms in quite a while so I don't have a ready answer for you, but if it's client side then you should be able to debug the javascript and find the source of the problem that way; let me try it real quick.

Comment: Sounds more like a Browser and/or html limitation to me since a FileUpload is nothing more than a html input type="file".

Comment: True, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851751/what-is-the-max-number-of-files-to-select-in-an-html5-multiple-file-input so it may depend on browser and length of filenames

Comment: Did a quick test, I can upload at least 1700+ files at once. (1 kb plain text files for testing, localhost, firefox)

Comment: Failed with around 3k files on chrome, but with short file names. IE doesn't fail outright but I can't see how many it selects, it cuts off at around 1.5k. Edge cuts off under 2k. Regardless, I would argue that uploading that many files through the browser is problematic and should be avoided...

Comment: Awesome thanks so much for the valuable information guys! 
I guess making use of a different jQuery file upload plugin won't make a difference? My client is used to the file name format, so I can't change that unfortunately. Unless there is some sort of file upload API that I can use. The other option would be to allow the user to upload the files in batches of 50-100 files or so.