# Php multiple image upload fails when i select many images

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading, image-resizing, php-ini

I use this code below, to upload and resize multiple images.

If i select about 10-20 image, everything works fine, but if i select 50 or more images, nothing happens, the page just reloads after a few seconds.

The code has some problem, or the max file size is limited in the ini file or server config?

[image]

[image]

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(isset($_FILES['gallery']))
    {
        foreach($_FILES['gallery']["name"] AS $key=>$file)
        {
            if($_FILES['gallery']['size'][$key]  != 0 )
            {
                $ThumbSquareSize        = $gallery_thumb_size;
                $BigImageMaxSize        = $gallery_big_size;
                $ThumbPrefix            = "th-";
                $DestinationDirectory   = '../images/gallery/';
                $Quality                = $imgQuality;
                if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['gallery']['tmp_name'][$key]))
                {
                    $error[] = "Elképzelhető, hogy nem választott ki fényképet.";
                }

                $RandomNumber   = $id.'-'.rand(0, 99999999);

                $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['gallery']['name'][$key]));
                $ImageSize      = $_FILES['gallery']['size'][$key] ;
                $TempSrc        =   $_FILES['gallery']['tmp_name'][$key];
                $ImageType      =   $_FILES['gallery']['type'][$key];
                switch(strtolower($ImageType))
                {
                    case 'image/png':
                        $CreatedImage =  imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['gallery']['tmp_name'][$key] );
                        break;
                    case 'image/gif':
                        $CreatedImage =  imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['gallery']['tmp_name'][$key]);
                        break;
                    case 'image/jpeg':
                    case 'image/pjpeg':
                        $CreatedImage = imagecreatefromjpeg(  $_FILES['gallery']['tmp_name'][$key]);
                        break;
                    default:
                    $error[] = "Nem támogatott fájlformátum.";
                }
                list($CurWidth,$CurHeight)=getimagesize($TempSrc);
                $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
                $ImageExt = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
                $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);
                $NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNumber.'.'.$ImageExt;
                $thumb_DestRandImageName    = $DestinationDirectory.$ThumbPrefix.$NewImageName;
                $DestRandImageName          = $DestinationDirectory.$NewImageName;
                if(!resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$BigImageMaxSize,$DestRandImageName,$CreatedImage,$Quality,$ImageType))
                {
                    $error[] = "A fénykép átméretezése nem sikerült.";

                }
                if(!cropImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$ThumbSquareSize,$thumb_DestRandImageName,$CreatedImage,$Quality,$ImageType))
                {
                    $error[] = "Nem sikerült a bélyegkép készítése.";
                }

                //$gallery_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($kapcs,  $_POST["images_alt"][ $key ] );
                $gallery_text = "";
                $gallery_thumb = basename( $thumb_DestRandImageName );
                $gallery_big = basename($DestRandImageName);
                $gallery_insert = "INSERT INTO gallery_item SET gallery_item_nev = '$gallery_text', gallery_item_thumb = '$gallery_thumb', gallery_item_big = '$gallery_big', gallery_id = '$id'";
                mysqli_query($kapcs , $gallery_insert ) or die( mysqli_error());
                header("Location: ".$host."/".$admin_folder."/galeria-szerkesztes.php?id=".$id."&new=1");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851751/what-is-the-max-number-of-files-to-select-in-an-html5-multiple-file-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update this settings in your php.ini

```
memory_limit = 256M
upload_max_size = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 1000
```

and then restart your server, check for updated changes in php.ini through browser and then upload images, if again you getting issue then increse this values to larger.

Comment: I didnt change the settings jet, but i tryed someting. I have a folder with 48 images. The folders size is 22 MB. It uploaded only 20 images of the 48. Why?

Comment: Because your max _file_uploads = 20,
Increse this limit to what ever you want to upload.

Comment: Aha, i understand. Thanks!

Comment: Okay welcome brother, if it is help full to you then give it a upvote or mark answer as right answer.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it helped. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Max file size is limited with 128 megabytes (or can be changes as per requirement). 
check in php.ini under variable

```
upload_max_filesize = **
post_max_size = **
```

Comment: How can i echo there settings on my page, to take a look?

Comment: check by php function phpinfo();, you can check all settings there

Comment: Okay, thanks! And thats only the problem? The size limit?

Comment: I added photos to the first post!